# js smooth stick navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, navigation, scroll

I have a question but I actually do not know how to ask.

I am trying to make a navigation bar stick on top when pass a point smoothly.

My reference is this -> http://blog.yjl.im/2010/01/stick-div-at-top-after-scrolling.html

My problem is when I use **IE or Chrome** to check it, there is a "**blink**" effect.

It is more like the scroll function will finish process after scroll over the point. So the things(HTML) after Nav will go on the top of the Nav on 0.1 ~ 0.3 secs then scroll function will finish process. Even through is short but it is visualize-able when the HTML over the nav.

However, If I use **Firefox** to check it, there is no such blink effect.....

*May I ask what is the problem here I got?? What Should I check about??*

My setting is a Anchor right before the Nav, Nav z-index = 99, and inside of the scroll function is below.

```
            $(this).scrollTop() > $(anchor).offset().top
            ? nav.addClass('sticky')
            : nav.removeClass('sticky')
```

Comment: Firefox has the smooth scroll option enabled by default which fires scroll events many times for each scroll while chrome only fires 1-2 scroll events, being one of them at the end of the default sharp scroll.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté Thank you very much, if so, how can I improve this?? When I check the reference example with Chrome or IE, they are just work fine...and how come I can not make it??

Comment: As events firing is more of a browser aspect, this may not be easy to work around. Will try out some tricks to check.

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    var my_nav = $('.navbar-sticky'); 
    // grab the initial top offset of the navigation 
    var sticky_navigation_offset_top = my_nav.offset().top;

    // our function that decides weather the navigation bar should have "fixed" css position or not.
    var sticky_navigation = function(){
        var scroll_top = $(window).scrollTop(); // our current vertical position from the top

        // if we've scrolled more than the navigation, change its position to fixed to stick to top, otherwise change it back to relative
        if (scroll_top > sticky_navigation_offset_top) { 
            my_nav.addClass( 'stick' );
        } else {
            my_nav.removeClass( 'stick' );
        }   
    };

    var initio_parallax_animation = function() { 
        $('.parallax').each( function(i, obj) {
            var speed = $(this).attr('parallax-speed');
            if( speed ) {
                var background_pos = '-' + (window.pageYOffset / speed) + "px";
                $(this).css( 'background-position', 'center ' + background_pos );
            }
        });
    }

    // run our function on load
    sticky_navigation();

    // and run it again every time you scroll
    $(window).scroll(function() {
         sticky_navigation();
         initio_parallax_animation();
    });

});
```